# How can I redefine stdout/stderr in bash?

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

Is it possible to redefine file descriptors (e.g. `stderr`) in bash?

I would like to send all output to a file by default while still being able to use the original `stderr` and `stdout`.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Error: foo bar" 1>2
REAL_STDERR=2
REAL_STDOUT=1
2=open("/tmp/stderr.log")
1=open("/tmp/stdout.log")
echo "This goes to stdout.log"
if ! curl doesntexist.yet; then
    echo "Error: Unable to reach host. See stderr.log for details" 1>REAL_STDERR
fi
```

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps names are specified for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell itself, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace (assigning to a shell variable that overlaps an existing environment variable's name will overwrite the latter), so naming conventions necessarily apply across both.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exec` builtin does this when not given a name of a command to run.

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2 2>/tmp/stderr.log >/tmp/stdout.log

echo "This goes to stdout.log"
echo "This goes to stderr.log" >&2

echo "This goes directly to real stderr" >&4
```

Note that redirections are processed in the order they're given on the command line left-to-right. Thus, `&1` and `&2` are interpreted as-modified by any previous redirections on the same command.

See [the relevant POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_20).

---

If you want to use variable names for your file descriptors (with the numbers automatically allocated), you'll need bash 4.1 or newer. There, you can do:

```
exec {real_stderr}>&2 {real_stdout}>&1 >stdout.log 2>stderr.log
echo "This goes stdout.log"
echo "This goes to stderr.log" >&2
echo "This goes to real stderr" >&$real_stderr
```